# Run npx webpack as part of Cloud Run deployment

Tags: docker, webpack, google-cloud-platform, web-deployment, google-cloud-run

I have a web application that's a hybrid of JS/NPM/Webpack for the frontend and Python/Django for the backend. The backend code and the source code for the frontend are stored in the code repository but the "compiled" frontend code is not as the expectation is that Webpack would build this code after deployment.

Currently, I have the following `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "Name",
  "description": "...",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npx webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=8.11.0",
    "node": ">=16.15.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    [...]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    [...]
  }
}
```

The app is deployed to Google Cloud's Run Cloud via the deploy command, specifically:

```
/gcloud/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gcloud run deploy [SERVICE-NAME] --source . --region us-west1 --allow-unauthenticated
```

However, the command `npx webpack --config webpack.config.js` is apparently never executed as the built files are not generated. Django returns the error:

```
Error reading /app/webpack-stats.json. Are you sure webpack has generated the file and the path is correct?
```

What's the most elegant/efficient way to execute the build command in production? Should I include in the Dockerfile via `RUN npx webpack --config webpack.config.js`? I'm not even sure this would work.

Edit 1:

My current `Dockerfile`:

```
# Base image is one of Python's official distributions.
FROM python:3.8.13-slim-buster

# Declare generic app variables.
ENV APP_ENVIRONMENT=Dev

# Update and install libraries.
RUN apt update
RUN apt -y install \
    sudo \
    curl \
    install-info \
    git-all \
    gnupg \
    lsb-release

# Install nodejs.
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_18.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN sudo apt install -y nodejs

RUN npx webpack --config webpack.config.js

# Copy local code to the container image. This is ncessary
# for the installation on Cloud Run to work.
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME
COPY . ./

# Handle requirements.txt first so that we don't need to re-install our
# python dependencies every time we rebuild the Dockerfile.
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Run the web service on container startup. Here we use the gunicorn
# webserver, with one worker process and 8 threads.
# For environments with multiple CPU cores, increase the number of workers
# to be equal to the cores available.
# Timeout is set to 0 to disable the timeouts of the workers to allow Cloud Run to handle instance scaling.
# Note that the $PORT variable is available by default on Cloud Run.
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT --workers 1 --threads 8 --timeout 0 --chdir project/ backbone.wsgi:application
```

Comment: Why don't you create your own container? Or use Buildpack directly to build the container and then deploy the container on Cloud Run?

Comment: I'm creating my own container with a dedicated Dockerfile. Should I run npx webpack within my own Dockerfile? @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: Yes,  I think. Or execute the npx webpack externally (for instance on Cloud Build) and copy the result in your container.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I can't seem to make it work. I just added my Dockerfile to the question, in case you could take a look. :)

Comment: I'd suggest to deploy the result of `npx webpack` and not the source files. Which means, the container for building it and the container for running it may not be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your error message (Error reading /app/webpack-stats.json), there is a reference to /app directory in webpack.config.js. It could be the problem, because at that point the directory does not exist. Try to run npx webpack command after WORKDIR /app.